# PHP condition, if current page, then link is highlighted

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, self

I have a webpage with a side bar that uses some css class.  If the class = "active', then the link will be highlighted.  I want to make it so that at any page, the script would check which link it's at, then decide which link to be highlighted.  Below is where I'm at, but I really don't have a clue how to proceed, please point me in the right and better direction! If I have 20 links, this script would be way too long.... Thank you!

---

```
<?php






$arr = array(

'1' => '/about.php', 
'2'=> '/abt-history2.php',
'3' => '/abt-shop.php',
);

$host =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


if($host == $arr['1']) 
{
    $class1 = "active";
}

else if ($host == $arr['2']) 
{
    $class2 = "active";
}

else if ($host == $arr['3']) 
{
    $class3 = "active";
}


 ?>






   <ul id="navigationSide">
      <div style="padding-left:20px; padding-bottom:10px; font-size:16px; font-weight:800; color:#777;">TITLE</div>
      <li><a href="<?php print $arr['1'];  ?>" class="<?php echo"$class1" ?>">AA</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php print $arr['2'];  ?>" class="<?php echo"$class2" ?>">BB</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="padding:5px;"></div>
    <ul id="navigationSide">
      <div style="padding-left:20px; padding-bottom:10px;  font-size:16px; font-weight:800; color:#777;">TITLE2</div>
      <li><a href="<?php print $arr['3'];  ?>" class="<?php echo"$class3" ?>" >CC</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: is that your original code? I can't find any host inside `$arr`, also, you used `$arr['abt-shop'];` but the key `abt-shop` is not there also

Comment: I have edited my original post.  The code works for me, but am still hoping to get a better way to keep the code small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is new, I removed all I had posted before, and this is what another answer. 
Since, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` gets `/Portal/TEST/file.php` in my localhost, I have added `/Portal/TEST/` in the script, you can remove it depending on the structure of your files.

```
<?php 
$arr = array(

'0' => '/Portal/TEST/about.php', 
'1'=> '/Portal/TEST/abt-history2.php',
'2' => '/Portal/TEST/abt-shop.php',
'3' => '/Portal/TEST/extra.php',
'3' => '/Portal/TEST/blaze.php',
);




 ?>


<h2>TITLE</h2>

<?php 

 for($i=0; $i< count($arr); $i++) {  



    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $arr[$i]) {

    $class = 'active';
 ?>


  <li><a href="<?php print $arr[$i];  ?>" class="<?php echo "$class".$i ?>"><?php echo $class ?>
</a></li>   <?php }else {
$class  = 'In active';

?>  
  <li><a href="<?php print $arr[$i];  ?>" class="<?php echo "$class".$i ?>"><?php echo $class ?>
</a></li> 

<?php
}

 }?>
```

Comment: the thing is, I have different title and different link sequence.. your's can only work with one title and one sequence... I'll put what I need as a front end to show you..

Comment: If I do it your way, I'll have to do a different for loop for each title, right?

Comment: If you want to add more links and more page, the ONLY thing you need to change is the two arrays, nothing else. This is as far as the code can be customized, there is no other way

Comment: ok let me try to work on this. thanks!

Comment: Please first try the codes I give you. Don't scan them with your eyes, and tell me it can do this and that. Have you tried it even?

Comment: mmm.. but that means I'll also need as many arrays for the name as the TITLEs that I have...

Comment: There are only two array, if you need to include a link to `contact.php` page, with a title `Contact` then, all you have to do, is add `contact.php` to the first array, and add `contact` to the title.

Comment: but if I need a second <h2>TITLE2</h2> with another set of links below it, how would you do it?

Comment: i know what you mean now, you want to generate the page according to the URI? Is that it?

Comment: for your " switch host" method, is it possible to not having to type all links?  I tried to add a for loop, but it hangs my system:     for($i=1; $i<4; $i++){ 
 switch($host){


 case $arr[$i];
        $class.$i = 'class="active"';
    break; 


 }

}

Comment: Yes, according to the URI, the same link as the URI should have a class linked to 'active'

Comment: So, if a user is on contact.php then, only contact.php should have the name active? is that it?

Comment: @Dave I just tried the above, script. It is completetly new just copy/paste and and tell me if it is working or not

Comment: Wait, I only the highlight is changed, I will make the 'un-active' the part now, just a minute

Comment: If you have contact.php in the array of URI's, and if someone is on that page, then it will be `highlighted` while saying `active`, but  what about for the the links that are not active? what do you want them to be? just menu, without being highlited? or you want them to say 'not active'

Comment: Ok,updated for the last time.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try
  <?php
    $arr = array(

      '1' => 'about.php', 
      '2'=> 'abt-history.php',
      '3' => 'abt-shop.php',
    );


    foreach($arr as $key => $page){

      $class = "";

      $currentPage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // check its value and get page name

      if($currentPage ==  $page){

       $class = 'class ="active"';
      }
    ?>
    <li>
        <a href ="yourdomainname/<?php echo $page; ?>" <?php echo $class; ?>>
           link<?= $key; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I actually have many other codes in between each link, like this:

Comment: <ul id="navigationSide">
  <div style="padding-left:20px; padding-bottom:10px; font-size:16px; font-weight:800; color:#777;">in媽咪簡介</div>
  <li><a href="<?php print $arr['1'];  ?>" class="<?php echo"$class1" ?>">來由</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php print $arr['2'];  ?>" class="<?php echo"$class2" ?>">XXXXXXX</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="padding:5px;"></div>
<ul id="navigationSide">
  <div style="padding-left:20px; padding-bottom:10px;  font-size:16px; font-weight:800; color:#777;">服務介紹</div>
  <li><a href="<?php print $arr['3'];  ?>" class="<?php echo"$class3" ?>" >購物中心</a></li>

Comment: I'm not sure how to loop the links without repeating all the other stuff..

Comment: I have attached my complete code in the original post.  SOrry I'm very new at this...

Comment: Use if else condition like $class1,$class2,etc or if else condition for each link

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is ok. Thing is, your keys end with `.php` and your `<li>` classes look up `abt-shop`, no `.php`, so they don't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I only understood

> If I have 20 links, this script would be way too long.... Thank you!

Well, that is when the `for` loop, comes in handy.

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<20; $i++){ ?>

<li>
    <a href ="<?php echo $arr['abt-shop']; ?>"
       class="<?php echo "$class.$i" ?>">
       link<?= $i; ?>
    </a>
</li>

<?php } ?>
```

**UPDATE**

---

```
<?php $arr = array( '1' => '/about.php', 
                    '2'=> '/abt-history2.php',
                    '3' => '/abt-shop.php', );


 $host = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


 switch($host){

 case $arr['1'];
        $class1 = "active";
    break; 
case $arr['2'];
        $class2 = "active";
    break; 
case $arr['3'];
        $class3 = "active";
    break; 
case $arr['4'];
        $class4 = "active";
    break; 



 }
```

Comment: Seriously? ;) Just put a 20 in the loop and have 20 links?

Comment: @dbf if you understood his question, then the `Answer` button is free for everybody

Comment: I got this script below to work, but really not sure how to incorporate the for loop.  Please help here:

Comment: <?php






$arr = array(

'1' => '/about.php', 
'2'=> '/abt-history2.php',
'3' => '/abt-shop.php',
);

$host =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


if($host == $arr['1']) 
{
    $class1 = "active";
}

else if ($host == $arr['2']) 
{
    $class2 = "active";
}

else if ($host == $arr['3']) 
{
    $class3 = "active";
}




 ?>

Comment: @phpNoOb If you just incorporated his code into the loop and make a bit of sense out of it, then maybe you would have deserved a press on the upvote button .. and still deserve ;)

Comment: @Dave I have updated my answer, please next time clarify your question, because I did not understand the most part if not all.

Comment: php Noob, thanks.  Please see my latest update on my code.  I'm also trying to see if I can just put a variable for all 20 links, instead of having to create $class1, $class2, $class3..etc

Comment: @Dave are you kidding me? My first answer allows you to have 20 links without having to create $class1, $class2, $class3. Have you even tried my first answer?

Comment: @phpNoOb No I'm not kidding.. I'm not sure how to use that for loop into my existing div and li codes.. I tried it and the links repeat themselves... I'm new at this..

Comment: So, let me understand the problem. how many links do you want to show?

Comment: see my original post, I updated the menu structure.  I just put 3 there.  If 3 works, I'm sure I can continue with the rest...

Comment: why are you dividing the links to 2 and 1? I can only make you to loop three at the same time, because what you are doing does not make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand 'dividing links to 2 and 1?  I have 3 links there, each is different.  When link 1 is landed, the link on the menu should have class=active.  if link 2 is landed, the link2 on the menu should be active, and so on...

Comment: Give me 2 minutes, I will create something for I hope, is you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the fall back. I will paste the answer, as a new one

Comment: @Dave Ok, now try my [new](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15718952/1640606) answer